# Page Cannot be loaded with page number URL. Some error with :id carousel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

timtchoi.com

I use onClick functions to increment the page number. I also use the :id page number to choose my gif for that page. But for some reason when you search the page number, there's an error and the page won't load. but it's accessible while clicking through the buttons. I want direct links and it showing my gifs.

```
     <BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path ="/melee/falco/:id" component={MeleeFalco} />
        <Route path ="/melee/falcon/:id" component={MeleeFalcon} />
        <Route path ="/melee/marth/:id" component={MeleeMarth} />
        <Route path ="/melee" component={Melee} />
```

---

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
  import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
  import aLeft from '../melee/aLeft.png';
  import aRight from '../melee/aRight.png';

  export default class MeleeMarth extends Component {
    onNextButton(){
      this.props.match.params.id++;

      if(this.props.match.params.id === 9)
        this.props.match.params.id = 1;


 this.props.history.push(`/melee/marth/${this.props.match.params.id}`);
    }

    onPrevButton(){
      this.props.match.params.id--;

      if(this.props.match.params.id === 0)
        this.props.match.params.id = 8;


this.props.history.push(`/melee/marth/${this.props.match.params.id}`);
    }

    render() {


      return (
        <div className = "content text-center">
          <img src= {aLeft}
            onClick={this.onPrevButton.bind(this)}
            className="img-responsive" alt = "arrowBtn"/>


          <img src={require(`../melee/m${this.props.match.params.id}.gif`)}
            className="img-responsive" alt = "Combo"/>


          <img src={aRight}
            onClick={this.onNextButton.bind(this)}
            className="img-responsive" alt = "arrowBtn"/>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Seems Its server configuration problem, Are you using nginx ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr i'm not sure what Nginx is but no. I am using netlify to host my webpage.

Comment: Have you did any redirection rule ?, [Like](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/)

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Where can I learn about redirection rules? I don't think I have any. But my gut feeling is telling me i don't want redirection, i want those links to work

Comment: https://timtchoi.com/melee/marth/1 such as this one

Comment: Check link on my previous comment

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr so sorry, didn't notice that was a link haha

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr I was busy but I got it. Thank you So much, it was easy and works now (: